# Ubuntu 20.04: xanmod kernel not loading due to invalid signature

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, kernel

After installing xanmod kernel (with AptURL from the [official site](https://xanmod.org/)) on my Laptop and booting into the newly installed kernel I received following error message:

```
Loading Linux 5.15.24-xanmod1 ...
error: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.24-xanmodi has invalid signature.
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

After that I removed the xanmod kernel using synaptic ([synaptic removal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvhfP.png))

And installed it again this time following step by step [this tutorial](https://idroot.us/install-xanmod-kernel-ubuntu-20-04/) (logged in as root user in a Terminal)

I still get the same error message saying xanmod1 has an invalid signature.

I have following kernels installed: (output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-kernel`)

```
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-27-generic              5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                      amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic              5.13.0-30.33~20.04.1                      amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.24-xanmod1                5.15.24-xanmod1-0~git20220216.6c16085     amd64        Linux kernel, version 5.15.24-xanmod1
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.13.0.30.33~20.04.17                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By **disabling Secure Boot** in UEFI Settings I resolved the issue and can now finally boot into the custom kernel installation!

Output of `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 5.15.24-xanmod1 (root@mascote) (gcc-11 (Debian 11.2.0-12) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.37) #0~git20220216.6c16085 SMP Wed Feb 16 15:00:21 UTC 2022
```